How to disable laptop keyboard in wayland?
How can I disable laptop keyboard in wayland system? I have found many ways in different websites. But all of them are for x11 system. How do I disable laptop keyboard in wayland system?

Refer to this answer https://superuser.com/a/1823603/950471. It's a tottally working solution!
